# Only first call works in multiple drawElements calls with same vertex buffers

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, webgl, shader

I am trying to render a model under multiple light sources using multiple drawElement calls with different light sources. The gist of the code is as follows.

```
    this.setUniform("u_matrix", "Matrix4fv", false, matrix);
    this.setUniform("u_nMatrix", "Matrix3fv", false, nMatrix);

    this.setUniform("u_kSpecular", "3fv", material.specular);
    this.setUniform("u_kDiffuse", "3fv", material.diffuse);
    this.setUniform("u_kAmbient", "3fv", material.ambient);
    this.setUniform("u_shininess", "1f", material.shininess);

    this.setVertexAttribArray("a_position", new Float32Array(mesh.vertices), 3);
    this.setVertexAttribArray("a_normal", new Float32Array(mesh.vertexNormals), 3);
    this.setElementArray(new Uint16Array(mesh.indices));

    for(var i = 0;i < lights.length;i++) {
        if(i == 1) {
            gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
            gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE);
            gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
        }
        var light = lights[i];
        console.dir(light);
        this.setUniform("u_lightType", "1i", light.type);
        this.setUniform("u_lightVector", "3fv", light.vector);
        this.setUniform("u_lightColor", "3fv", light.color);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, mesh.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
    gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
```

The issue here is that only the first lighting is rendered. Subsequent drawElements do not render anything. I do not think the issue is with my shader code, because the issue persists even if I strip the shader down to just set fragment color equal to the light type or some such parameter.

`setUniform` `setVertexAttribArray` and `setElementArray` are some helpers that i have written. They basically look like this:

```
setElementArray: function(array) {
    var gl = this.gl;
    var buffer = this._arrBuffers.__indexBuffer;
    if(_.isUndefined(buffer)) {
        buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        this._arrBuffers.__indexBuffer = buffer;
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

setVertexAttribArray: function(name, array, size, type, normalized, stride, offset) {
    var gl = this.gl;
    size = size || 2;
    type = type || gl.FLOAT;
    normalized = normalized || false;
    stride = stride || 0;
    offset = offset || 0;

    var buffer = this._arrBuffers[name];
    if(_.isUndefined(buffer)) {
        buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        this._arrBuffers[name] = buffer;
    }
    var location = this.getLocation(name, true);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(location);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(location, size, type, normalized, stride, offset);
}
```

Comment: is this supposed to render in a draw loop or do you want to render a single frame?

Comment: then you may want to look into which calls are actually needed to be made in a draw loop. You are currently re-buffering all your vertices on every frame, which is very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I had set `gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS)`, so subsequent renderings failed the depth test. Setting `gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL)` solved the problem.